# zero coupon problem calculus

Tags: options, stochastic-calculus, pricing, zero-coupon

I encounter a problem: do we have the following equality : 
$B(0,T_{i})e^{\int_{0}^{t}r_{s}ds}=B(t,T_{i})$ and if yes why because I am stuck with this ... I try to use that : $B(t,T_{i}) = B(0,T_{i})e^{\int_{0}^{t}r_{s}ds-0.5\int_{0}^{t}vol^{2}ds+\int_{0}^{t}voldW_{s}}$
Thanks !

Question revised:

Actually my question is the following : the forward price at t is defined by :$F_{t,T}=Price(t)/B(t,T)$. Let be $Price(t)=E_{Q}[e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r_{s}ds}Payoff|F_{t}]$. By using the forward measure defined by : $dQ^{T}=(e^{-\int_{0}^{T}r_{s}ds}/B(0,T) )dQ$ we have that : $Price(t)=E_{Q^{T}}[e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r_{s}ds}Payoff*B(0,T)/e^{-\int_{0}^{T}r_{s}ds}|F_{t}]$. I need to prove that this last equality is $E_{Q^{T}}[Payoff|F_{t}]*B(t,T)$ so that $Price(t)/B(t,T)=E_{QT}[Payoff|F_{t}]$ which is a "formula" I know.

Comment: Please define $r_s$. Is this the riskfree rate?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation looks correct if B(t,T(i)) is a **forward price** of an instrument paying no dividends.  The second equation looks correct if B(t,T(i)) is a **random variable** being projected by a lognormal process

Comment: Actually, $B(t,T)$ is the price of a zero coupon with maturity T

Comment: But how can we show that with the calculus I began

Answer (score 1):

Let $r_t$ be the interest rate. Then 
\begin{align*}
B(t, T_i) &= E\Big[e^{\big(-\int_t^{T_i} r_s ds\big)} \mid \mathscr{F}_t\Big]\\
&= e^{\int_0^t r_s ds} E\Big[e^{\big(-\int_0^{T_i} r_s ds\big)} \mid \mathscr{F}_t\Big].
\end{align*}
Note that, for $t>0$, unless $r_t$ is deterministic,
\begin{align*}
 E\Big[e^{\big(-\int_0^{T_i} r_s ds\big)} \mid \mathscr{F}_t\Big] &\ne  E\Big[e^{\big(-\int_0^{T_i} r_s ds\big)}\Big]\\
&= B(0, T_i),
\end{align*}
as $$E\Big[e^{\big(-\int_0^{T_i} r_s ds\big)} \mid \mathscr{F}_t\Big]$$ is an $\mathscr{F}_t$ measurable random variable, while $$E\Big[e^{\big(-\int_0^{T_i} r_s ds\big)}\Big]$$ is a constant.

In conclusion, the identity $B(0,T_{i})e^{\int_{0}^{t}r_{s}ds}=B(t,T_{i})$ is **incorrect**, unless the interest rate is deterministic.

> Addition based on the revision.

Consider the payoff $Payoff_T$ at time $T$. Then the value at time $t$, where $0 \le t \le T$, under the risk-neutral probability measure $Q$, is given by
\begin{align*}
Price(t) = E_Q\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} Payoff_T \mid \mathscr{F}_t\right).
\end{align*}
Let $Q_T$ be the $T$-forward probability measure. Then,
\begin{align*}
\eta_t &\equiv \frac{dQ}{dQ_T}\big|_{\mathscr{F}_t}\\
&=\frac{e^{\int_0^t r_s ds} B(0, T)}{B(t, T)}.
\end{align*}
Using the abstract Bayes formula, 
\begin{align*}
E_Q\left(e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} Payoff_T \mid \mathscr{F}_t\right) &= E_{Q_T}\left(\frac{\eta_T}{\eta_t}e^{-\int_t^T r_s ds} Payoff_T \mid \mathscr{F}_t\right)\\
&=B(t, T) E_{Q_T}\left( Payoff_T \mid \mathscr{F}_t\right).
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
E_{Q_T}\left( Payoff_T \mid \mathscr{F}_t\right) = \frac{Price(t)}{B(t, T)}.
\end{align*}